# What is the cabling on the exterior of the SLS solid rocket boosters that wasn't on the shuttle solid rocket boosters?

Tags: identify-this-object, sls, srb, artemis-program

I noticed what appears to be foamed-over cabling running roughly parallel to the systems tunnel on the exterior of the SLS Solid Rocket Boosters (SRBs). The cabling appears to run all the way from the forward to the aft skirt.

Highlighted in yellow here:

[image]

The shuttle SRBs didn't have this cabling:

[image]

Descriptions I've seen of the differences between the SRBs for the two vehicles didn't include this cabling. What is it for?

Image sources: [SLS](https://images.nasa.gov/details-KSC-20220421-PH-JBS01_0121), [STS](https://www.nasa.gov/images/content/540055main_launchpad-threearms.jpg)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is the new "systems tunnel" the runs up to the forward skirt avionics. This cabling is to connect the forward skirt avionics (where the majority of the avionics are) with the aft skirt TVC controllers and any sensors on the SRB stack. In addition any sensors that sent a signal to the orbiter aft through the Shuttle 17" disconnect would need to send that to the forward skirt. Better view with the cables exposed:
https://www.nasa.gov/exploration/systems/sls/fs/solid-rocket-booster.html

https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/thumbnails/image/artemis_i_boosters_and_core_stage.jpg

See "systems tunnel":

https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20150016519/downloads/20150016519.pdf
https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20200002334/downloads/20200002334.pdf

[image: View of the STS Solid Rocket Booster cabling exposed in the VAB (Vehicle Assembly Building)]

Comment: This is close to a link only answer. Please explain the links. @GandalfDDl

Comment: This is good info, but does not answer "what is it for" - the new cabling, that is. To get the checkmark, that specific info is required in the answer.

Comment: OK, clarified. Basically all the sensors / commands would need to transit up to the forward skirt where the main aviounics packages are now located for the SRBs.